# Android Google Map to show as picture

Tags: android, google-maps, imageview, android-imageview

I've implemented Google Maps V2 in my android app and now I would like to do something differently. I'm showing a location (longitude, latitude) with a marker. The problem is that this is showing in my activity as a Map. I would like to show it as a ImageView and only if someone clicks on it show the map interface.

Basically what I want to do is a static preview of the location and display it as a picture (with a frame and rounded corners) When clicked then open maps and give all functionality.

Is there a way to put a map fragment into a ImageView?

Any help you can provide will greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the Google Maps built-in snapshot method, to capture a preview and display it in an `ImageView`. You can style the `ImageView` in any way you like, and also set a clickListener that does something, when the preview is clicked. Here's an example:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(35.0116363, 135.7680294);
// Add Marker
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
// Center map on the marker
CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 4.0f);
mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);

final ImageView mapPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapPreview);
mapPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Hide the preview, to reveal the map
        mapPreview.setImageBitmap(null);
        mapPreview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));

        // Or start Google Maps app
//      String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", 50.0, 0.1);
//      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
//      startActivity(intent);
    }
});

mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        // Make a snapshot when map's done loading
        mMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                mapPreview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                mapPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                // If map won't be used afterwards, remove it's views
//              ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.map)).removeAllViews();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23):

There is a slightly different option that can achieve the same result and requires very little coding, provided your app can use the network: you can call the [**Google Static Maps API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to ask for an map image with arbitrary center, zoom level, size, and other features such as markers and paths.

For example the link:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=14&size=600x300&key=**YOUR_MAP_API_KEY**

produces the following image:

[image]

This makes it very easy to display a map in an `ImageView` widget: you just need to build the appropriate URL from the location data and dimensions, and then display the image with any of the image loading frameworks such as Picasso, Volley, &c. We've using this feature for a couple of years now.

This is especially useful when displaying, say, a `ListView` of little maps. In those situations, asking for *n* snapshots will be problematic, while *n* image downloads should work just fine.

---

A third option, which will become available in the next week or so, according to [this announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/11/google-play-services-65.html), is the new **Lite Maps** mode which will be released as part of Google Play Services 6.5:

> In addition, there is also a new ‘lite mode’ map option, ideal for
> situations where you want to provide a number of smaller maps, or a
> map that is so small that meaningful interaction is impractical, such
> as a thumbnail in a list. A lite mode map is a bitmap image of a map
> at a specified location and zoom level.
>
> In lite mode, markers and shapes are drawn client-side on top of the
> static image, so you still have full control over them. Lite mode
> supports all of the map types, the My Location layer, and a subset of
> the functionality of a fully-interactive map.

Sounds exactly like what you need, provided you can wait a few days for the updated SDK. :)

Comment: This answer is useful when you small number of locations but I need to add many more locations which is not working because, of URL length limit...
Any other solution?

Comment: googlemap static api require billing, not free