# How to take google maps snapshot without actually displaying the map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-googleapiclient

I want to be able to take a screenshot of a certain location in google maps without actually loading the google map onto the screen, If there is a way google map can take the screenshot in the  background that would be great.

Comment: Do you mean an image of what the map with the interface and controls would look like on the screen? Or just the actual map without the user interface?

Comment: Yes, an image of what the map would look like if it were on the screen

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite):

> **The Google Maps Android API can serve a static image as a 'lite mode' map.**
>
> A lite mode map is a bitmap image of a map at a specified location and zoom level. Lite mode supports all of the map types (normal, hybrid, satellite, terrain) and a subset of the functionality supplied by the full API. Lite mode is useful when you want to provide a number of maps in a stream, or a map that is too small to support meaningful interaction.

Example:

**As an XML attribute for a MapView or MapFragment**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="13"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:liteMode="true"/>
```

**In the GoogleMapOptions object**

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions().liteMode(true);
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite#supported_api_features) You can find supported features.

---

In addition I recommend reading: [Android Google Map to show as picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946503/android-google-map-to-show-as-picture)

> You can use the Google Maps built-in snapshot method, to capture a preview and display it in an ImageView.